# Windows 7 Dualview: Allow mouse transfer to smaller monitor on complete display height

Tags: windows, mouse, monitor, multiple-monitors

I have a 2 monitor setup, a large 2560x1440 main monitor and a second 1080p monitor to the left. However, there's always a significant amount of screenheight where my mouse gets stuck when I try to switch to the smaller monitor. Is there a way in Windows 7 (or through a Nvidia Driver Setting) to always be able to switch to the smaller monitor when I move my mouse over the left edge of my primary monitor? I'm aware that I can drag/arrange the monitor icons, but theres always a certain area where my mouse will still get stuck, either top or bottom.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/cA5Jl.png

Comment: This would be more on-topic on http://superuser.com/

Comment: thanks for the hint! It was new for me that there are several stack exchange formats/platforms. I'll try my luck there :)